# Why there is need of person in MNC's to deal with Power BI?

Tags: tableau-api, powerbi, business-intelligence

I am new to Power BI. I want to clarify "Why in organizations there is need of Power BI guy?"

Moreover, Project Manager can also do the task of Power BI developer. But why they need different person.

What exactly the daily routing of a Power BI developer?

I hope you guys understand my questions.

Cheers,
Mohit

Comment: Broad, unclear, and not really a programming question.

Comment: This more like a interview question rather than a programming question... this site is more into solving any issues if  you face in power BI rather than why to use powerBI

Comment: I know its not related to programming, I still wanted to know abt it. Thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project managers are not BI developers; any organization interested in implementing a BI solution will need a BI developer.

Bi developers usually focus on developing BI tools, this can range from creating simple front end visualizations to creating/maintaining database solutions to drive these tools.

We understand the question but SO is geared more toward solving programming issues you've already taken a crack at.

Cheers Mohit27 and welcome ;)

Comment: No problem @Mohiit27